# GRUB does not install in a clean installation

Tags: grub2

I have installed Windows 10 with EFI on the main NVME disk with Intel Optane 500gb. In another 500 Gb SSD I have made the partitions to install Kubuntu, sda1 for root, sda2 for home and nvme0n1 for GRUB.
I do all the installation without problem, but when rebooting the computer goes directly to Windows 10 without appearing before GRUB and being able to choose with which system I boot.
I think GRUB does not install or Windows deletes GRUB
How can i fix this?

Comment: Can you go to the boot menu and change the boot order?

Comment: Systems often need UEFI update and SSD firmware update for Ubuntu's installer Ubiquity to see SSD. And it does not matter what you select during UEFI install, it only installs grub to first drive. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 & 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1229488

Comment: I have an EFI partition that was created by Windows 10 installation

The hard drive nvme0n1 has:

nvme0n1p1 - EFI partition;
nvme0n1p2 - Optane Partition;
nvme0n1p3 - Windows 10 OS Partition;

Regarding what I have read, I have to install grub on the EFI partition, that is, on my computer it would be the nvme0n1p1 partition where the EFI partition that Windows 10 created when installed is installed.

Comment: The EFI partition that created Windows 10 has 260 Mb and I think it is 100% occupied

Comment: I have already installed Kubuntu on the same computer and everything went relatively well, the difference is that I now have windows 10 installed and when doing the same steps as the installation without windows 10, When I reboot GRUB does not appear and it enters windows 10 directly, just I need to know where to install GRUB exactly and why I should install it in the recommended place, some users have given me advice in the Kubuntu official channel chat that is more to affect all my windows installation than to really help and if I request explain to me why your recommendation they get bother